# Elasticsearch .Net client 8 Aggs filter

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch client for .Net from official page here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/installation.html)

I'm stuck when convert aggs query to .Net code;

My aggs from query here:

```
{
    "account": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "account_id",
            "size": 2000,
            "order": {
                "sum_of_fee_by_sub_type_sort >total_fee.value": "desc"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "sum_of_fee_by_sub_type_sort": {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "sub_type": 21
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "total_fee": {
                        "sum": {
                            "field": "total_fee"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "sum_of_fee": {
                "sum": {
                    "field": "total_fee"
                }
            },
            "by_sub_type": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "sub_type"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "sum_of_fee_by_sub_type": {
                        "sum": {
                            "field": "total_fee"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code to apply filter aggs:

```
return aa.Filters("sum_of_fee_by_sub_type_sort", ft => 
                    ft
                        .Aggregations(totalFee => totalFee
                        .Sum("total_fee", sum => sum.Field("total_fee"))
                    )
                );
```

the ft variable can not .Filter, it just have Filters() but I'm stuck to using it. Please help me
Thank you